# my textview are shorten if I don't set an enought large string in my layout :S

Tags: android

I've a very strange issue, 
when i try to set the text on one of my textView, the text appear entirely only if i've set in my layout a bigget text. if the text in my layout is smaller, the new string is shorten between two words to fit the smaller place.
if i don't set text in my layout, it simply doesn't appear !

Have you an idea where i have to look for ?

(I'm in a custom view group involving three layout in the same activity, without fragments)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Jury"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <com.clicmobile.cannes.widget.AspectRatioImageView
        android:id="@+id/juryPrezImageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/juryPrezIcHiddenImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/juryFonctionPrezTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/juryPrezIcHiddenImageView"

            android:text="President du jury - " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/juryCategoryTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/juryFonctionPrezTextView"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/juryFonctionPrezTextView"
            android:text="cinefondation et courts metrages" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/juryPrezIcImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

            android:layout_below="@id/juryCategoryTextView"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/juryNomPrezTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/juryPrezIcImageView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/juryPrezIcImageView"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:minWidth="50dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/juryFonctionTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/juryNomPrezTextView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/juryPrezIcImageView"
            android:text="realisateur" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/juryMemberTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/juryFonctionTextView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/juryPrezIcImageView"
            android:text="Membre du jury" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/juryMemberTextView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/juryPrezIcImageView"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/juryMembrelinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/juryMembre1RelativeLayout"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/juryMembre1ImageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/juryMembre1NomTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/juryMembre1ImageView"
                android:text="machin"
                android:textSize="22dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/juryMember1FonctionTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/juryMembre1NomTextView"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/juryMembre1ImageView"
                android:text="fonction du jury" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/juryMembre2RelativeLayout"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/juryMembre2ImageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/juryMembre2NomTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/juryMembre2ImageView"
                android:text="machin"
                android:textSize="22dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/juryMember2FonctionTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/juryMembre2NomTextView"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/juryMembre2ImageView"
                android:text="fonction du jury" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: use android:minWidth="50dp" for your TextView

Comment: why ? i don't understand

Comment: it doesn't work anyway, the text I enter is shorten to 50dp

Comment: sorry, I didnt get you questions. be more clear. if possible attach screenshot.

Comment: well, when i set in my textBox the property android:text with a string of for example 100dp long, when i change it in my java with .setText(), only 100dp of the new string is shown.

Comment: post the xml part that declares the textview

Comment: I am totally confused ?!!!!!!

Comment: i didn't posted it because i'm not very allowed to. I hope you'll not tell my boss

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is happening because the second TextView is adjusting its size to the first TextView. So, if the first TextView fills lets say 50% of the screen then the second one will not be able to exceed this size.

Try setting the layout_width to wrap_content on the second TextView, if it does not work then please show your xml layout so we can help.

Comment: Thank you, could you tell me which is the name of the text view you are having trouble with?

Comment: i just remarqued that I've the same (quite) with my images, when a change the sources, the height of my image cannot be changed

Comment: every one, it's the same thing for every one (i've trouble to get your messages right the way sorry for the delay)